# "Reciprocity law" for non-rook chess pieces

Tags: combinatorics

There is a reciprocity law relating rook numbers for a given board and the complementary board, the [Rook Reciprocity Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RookReciprocityTheorem.html). Is there a similar reciprocity law for non-rook chess pieces?

Comment: Can you say a few more words about what a "rook number" is and what you mean by the "complementary board"? The link doesn't help there at all.

Comment: @example: A *board* is a subset $B$ of $[n]\times[n]$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z^+$; the *complementary board* is $([n]\times[n])\setminus B$. The *rook numbers* $r_k(B)$ give the numbers of ways of placing $k$ mutually non-attacking rooks on $B$, i.e., the number of $k$-element subsets of $B$ such that no two elements have the same first or the same second coordinate.